# How to do a case-insensitive selection in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, prepared-statement

I need help with making a case-insensitive selection in a MySQL database.
I've found a solution to doing this in MySQL, but have been unable to translate it to Java.

This is the MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM allclient where name="Zdi0" collate utf8_bin
```

Which works, but in java:

```
PreparedStatement pstm = mysql.Pstm("SELECT id,name FROM allclient WHERE   user =  ? collate utf8_bin  AND pass = ? ");
pstm.setString(1, this.name);
pstm.setString(2, this.pass);
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Generates this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at Luncher4.run(Luncher4.java:96)
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It's not clear what you're after, but have you tried `WHERE name LIKE 'Zdi0'` ? The `LIKE` operator is case insensitive unlike `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case insensitive queries in MySQL as examples:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE UPPER(username) = 'ZDI';
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(username) = 'zdi';
```

Comment: the problem is not UPPER or LOWER but i need the result give me exactly the same name searched